# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser'

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, tomcat, graphql

I am trying to save the data in the database[PostgresQL] using graphql with JPA, spring-boot. I have created the schema and created the resolver.
I have created the Repository for the same.
While running the main java class it shows the below error.
It shows the error in resolver like there is no root resolver for the query type query.

````
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at com.example.demo.DemographqlApplication.main(DemographqlApplication.java:9) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaClassScannerError: No Root resolvers for query type 'Query' found!  Provide one or more com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.GraphQLQueryResolver to the builder.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaClassScannerError: No Root resolvers for query type 'Query' found!  Provide one or more com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.GraphQLQueryResolver to the builder.
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaClassScanner$RootTypesHolder.createRootType(SchemaClassScanner.kt:424) ~[graphql-java-tools-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaClassScanner$RootTypesHolder.<init>(SchemaClassScanner.kt:405) ~[graphql-java-tools-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaClassScanner.scanForClasses(SchemaClassScanner.kt:78) ~[graphql-java-tools-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParserBuilder.scan(SchemaParserBuilder.kt:151) ~[graphql-java-tools-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParserBuilder.build(SchemaParserBuilder.kt:157) ~[graphql-java-tools-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.schemaParser(GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.java:57) ~[graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure-5.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7201a319.CGLIB$schemaParser$2(<generated>) ~[graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure-5.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7201a319$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$52dead8e.invoke(<generated>) ~[graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure-5.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7201a319.schemaParser(<generated>) ~[graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure-5.0.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 19 common frames omitted```

**Model/autor.java**

    @Entity
public class Author { 
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Long id;

      @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
      private String name;

      @Column(name = "age")
      private Integer age;

      public Author() {
      }

      public Author(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      public Author(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
      }

      public Long getId() {
        return id;
      }

      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }
      
      public void setName(String name) {
         this.name=name; 
      }
      
      public void setAge(Integer age) {
          this.age=age;
          
      }
      public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
          }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
      }


}

**model/tutorial.java**

    ```@Entity
public class Tutorial {
    @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private Long id;

      @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
      private String title;

      @Column(name = "description")
      private String description;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
      private Author author;

      public Tutorial() {
      }

      public Tutorial(String title, String description, Author author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.author = author;
      }

      public Long getId() {
        return id;
      }

      public String getTitle() {
        return title;
      }

      public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
      }

      public String getDescription() {
        return description;
      }

      public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
      }

      public Author getAuthor() {
        return author;
      }

      public void setAuthor(Author author) {
        this.author = author;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return "Tutorial [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", description=" + description + ", author=" + author + "]";
      }

}```

**Author Repository**

    ```import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.*;
import com.example.demo.model.Author;
public interface AuthorRepository extends JpaRepository<Author, Long>{

}```


**Tutorial repository**

    ```import com.example.demo.model.Tutorial;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.*;

public interface TutorialRepository extends JpaRepository<Tutorial, Long> {}```

**Mutation resolver**

    ``` import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.demo.model.Author;
import com.example.demo.model.Tutorial;
import com.example.demo.repository.AuthorRepository;
import com.example.demo.repository.TutorialRepository;

//import graphql.kickstart.tools.GraphQLMutationResolver;
import javassist.NotFoundException;
import com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.GraphQLMutationResolver;

@Component
public class Mutation implements GraphQLMutationResolver {
    private AuthorRepository authorRepository;
      private TutorialRepository tutorialRepository;

      @Autowired
      public Mutation(AuthorRepository authorRepository, TutorialRepository tutorialRepository) {
        this.authorRepository = authorRepository;
        this.tutorialRepository = tutorialRepository;
      }

      public Author createAuthor(String name, Integer age) {
        Author author = new Author();
        author.setName(name);
        author.setAge(age);

        authorRepository.save(author);

        return author;
      }

      public Tutorial createTutorial(String title, String description, Long authorId) {
        Tutorial tutorial = new Tutorial();
        tutorial.setAuthor(new Author(authorId));
        tutorial.setTitle(title);
        tutorial.setDescription(description);

        tutorialRepository.save(tutorial);

        return tutorial;
      }

      public boolean deleteTutorial(Long id) {
        tutorialRepository.deleteById(id);
        return true;
      }

      public Tutorial updateTutorial(Long id, String title, String description) throws NotFoundException {
        Optional<Tutorial> optTutorial = tutorialRepository.findById(id);

        if (optTutorial.isPresent()) {
          Tutorial tutorial = optTutorial.get();

          if (title != null)
            tutorial.setTitle(title);
          if (description != null)
            tutorial.setDescription(description);

          tutorialRepository.save(tutorial);
          return tutorial;
        }

        throw new NotFoundException("Not found Tutorial to update!");
      }

}```

**Query-resolver**

    ```   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.demo.model.Author;
import com.example.demo.model.Tutorial;
import com.example.demo.repository.AuthorRepository;
import com.example.demo.repository.TutorialRepository;
//import com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.GraphQLQueryResolver

import graphql.kickstart.tools.GraphQLQueryResolver;


@Component
public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

     private AuthorRepository authorRepository;
      private TutorialRepository tutorialRepository;

      @Autowired
      public Query(AuthorRepository authorRepository, TutorialRepository tutorialRepository) {
        this.authorRepository = authorRepository;
        this.tutorialRepository = tutorialRepository;
      }

      public Iterable<Author> findAllAuthors() {
        return authorRepository.findAll();
      }

      public Iterable<Tutorial> findAllTutorials() {
        return tutorialRepository.findAll();
      }

      public long countAuthors() {
        return authorRepository.count();
      }

      public long countTutorials() {
        return tutorialRepository.count();
      }

}```


**Tutorial Resolver**

    ```import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.GraphQLResolver;
import com.example.demo.model.Author;
import com.example.demo.model.Tutorial;
import com.example.demo.repository.AuthorRepository;

@Component
public class TutorialResolver implements GraphQLResolver<Tutorial> {

     @Autowired
      private AuthorRepository authorRepository;

      public TutorialResolver(AuthorRepository authorRepository) {
        this.authorRepository = authorRepository;
      }

      public Author getAuthor(Tutorial tutorial) {
        return authorRepository.findById(tutorial.getAuthor().getId()).orElseThrow(null);
      }
}```

**application.properties**

    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spgraphql_demo
spring.datasource.username=login
spring.datasource.password=admin@123
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.main.web-application-type=none
````

Comment: You are providing the exception, however I dont see any code.  Resolver? Schema? Directory Structure?

Comment: Query class is implementing graphql.kickstart.tools.GraphQLQueryResolver and your application is expecting com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.GraphQLQueryResolver

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this suggestion but still I am facing the issue.